# Copy wordpress site to local server (xampp)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem, because I have to copy a live wordpress site to my local server (xampp). But the site php version is out of date and the phpmyadmin database too, so I can not import the database. And if I upgrade the php version, the site can no longer be reached. What is a good way to copy the site to the local server.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: have you tried plugin Duplicator?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to dump the database with mysql command line interface using ssh from the server. Then try to import the database in local phpmyadmin with `SQL compatibility` mode as  `MYSQL40`. It may work.

[image]